# Changing the default WordPress hashing algorithm from MD5 to ARGON2ID, without a plugin in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords

I want to change MD5 in wordpress to ARGON2ID. I don't trust plugins because most of them are not updated regularly and I don't think they are secure enough.

1. how can I implement ARGON2ID in my *wp-includes/pluggable.php* file so that all passwords are hashed with ARGON2ID instead of the default MD5 hash algorithm?
2. do I need to change anything else in other files?
3. when I update WordPress or PHP, how can I do it so I don't lose my configuration?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

I have tried some plugins that work well. But I want to minimise plugins because of speed and security. And most of the plugins are not updated for years. ALso I think most plugins for this load a lot or bloat, so I want to program it myself.

This is the code I think I need to put in the *wp-includes/pluggable.php* file:
Is there more, or is this code even good?

```
<?php
/**
 * Hashes a password using Argon2.
 *
 * @param string $password The password to hash.
 * @return string The hashed password.
 */
function hash_password($password) {
    // Set the parameters for the Argon2 algorithm
    $memory_cost = 65536; // 64 MB
    $time_cost = 4;
    $threads = 4;
    
    // Generate a random salt
    $salt = random_bytes(16);
    
    // Hash the password using Argon2
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID, [
        'memory_cost' => $memory_cost,
        'time_cost' => $time_cost,
        'threads' => $threads,
        'salt' => $salt,
    ]);
    
    // Return the hashed password
    return $hash;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To create a plugin for WordPress that uses Argon2 for password hashing, you can follow these steps:

Create a new directory in the wp-content/plugins directory with a unique name for your plugin.
In that directory, create a new PHP file with the same name as the directory.
In that PHP file, define a function that replaces the default password hashing algorithm with Argon2. Here's an example:

```
function my_plugin_hash_password( $password ) {
    // Set the parameters for the Argon2 algorithm
    $memory_cost = 65536; // 64 MB
    $time_cost = 4;
    $threads = 4;

    // Generate a random salt
    $salt = random_bytes(16);

    // Hash the password using Argon2
    $hash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID, [
        'memory_cost' => $memory_cost,
        'time_cost'   => $time_cost,
        'threads'     => $threads,
        'salt'        => $salt,
    ] );

    // Return the hashed password
    return $hash;
}

function my_plugin_wp_check_password( $password, $hash, $user_id ) {
    $check = password_verify( $password, $hash );
    if ( $check && password_needs_rehash( $hash, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID ) ) {
        wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );
    }
    return $check;
}

// Hook the my_plugin_hash_password function to the password_hash filter
add_filter( 'password_hash', 'my_plugin_hash_password', 10, 1 );

// Hook the my_plugin_wp_check_password function to the wp_check_password filter
add_filter( 'wp_check_password', 'my_plugin_wp_check_password', 10, 3 );
```

Save the file and activate the plugin through the WordPress dashboard.
The above code replaces the default WordPress password hashing algorithm with Argon2 using the password_hash filter. It also adds a filter for the wp_check_password function to verify and update existing passwords when necessary.

Regarding the use of the sodium library, Argon2 does not require it, but it can be used as a more secure alternative to the default random number generator in PHP. However, if your hosting provider does not have the sodium library installed, you can still use Argon2 without it.

Comment: Thank you very much.
How exactly can i makte this in a plugin. Because I just created a php file in the wp-content/plugins folder, I can enable it but it doesn't work? maybe the built in password_hash function of PHP should be used. I think it is also secure. Or is the sodium library needed for argon2? I use shared hosting, so I can't install the sodium library on my server.

Comment: @AYNTK there are so many posts and stack answers on how to create WP Plugin. As per my knowledge sodium library is more secure anyways I have edited my answer to create a plugin also to use password_hash function of PHP.